replace the default function in xtemplate
Here is the mwe:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xtemplate}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% 1. create a new object type
\DeclareObjectType{ObjA}{2}

% 2. create a new template for the object type
\DeclareTemplateInterface{ObjA}{TemplateA}{2}
  {
    keyA : function 2 = #1|#2,
  }
\DeclareTemplateCode{ObjA}{TemplateA}{2}
  {
    keyA = \func:nn,
  }{
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \func:nn {#1}{#2}AB
  }

% 3. create an instance of this template
\cs_set:Npn \__mwe_swap:nn #1#2 {#2<-->#1}
\DeclareInstance{ObjA}{InstA}{TemplateA}
  {
    keyA = \__mwe_swap:nn,            % bug
    % keyA = \__mwe_swap:nn {#1}{#2}, % working
  }

% 4. use this instance
\UseInstance{ObjA}{InstA}
  {ARG-1}{ARG-2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

The output is:
B<–>A

The first 2 tokens {#1}{#2} in \DeclareTemplateCode are absorbed by something i don't know about. The output i expect is:
ARG-2<–>ARG-1AB

If i replace keyA = \__mwe_swap:nn with keyA = \__mwe_swap:nn {#1}{#2} in \DeclareInstance, everything works right, but syntax in this form looks weird.

How is that a weird interface? The syntax is as it is because you can use keyA = #2<->#1 directly, you have to understand the parsing of keyA in the sense that it accepts the replacement text that should be assigned for \func:nn.

But you're right, there is either an implementation bug, or a documentation bug. See section 10 of xtemplate.pdf, the assignment in \SetTemplateKeys doesn't seem to work (though that's not the same as the code used in your question).

@Skillmon For that if  i add \cs_meaning:N \func:nn  in the final argument of \DeclareTemplateCode, the output is \long macro:#1#2->\__mwe_swap:nn, which implies that the function \func:nn have been set correctly. But the first 2 tokens missing.

\long macro:#1#2-> tells you that the macro will absorb 2 arguments, after the arrow comes the replacement text, which doesn't use #1 or #2 so both arguments are gobbled. If everything was as you intended to it'd look like \long macro:#1#2->\__mwe_swap:nn {#1}{#2}.
